# JSON Element order Validation in POSTMAN payload

Tags: arrays, postman, loops

With POSTMAN, I'm getting a JSON payload return.  I need to verify that the first time PoiId is returned that the value is 1234 and the 2nd instance of PoiId the value is 5678.  Validating that the order that the PoiId values are returned are correct.   I'm thinking of going about it as such:

I saw elsewhere that it is possible to set just PoiId to an array as such:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody),
    PoiId = [];
```

And the idea is to verify that at position [0] the value is 1234.  Sorry but am new to validating in Postman.   Would like suggestions.

Again, the order of the results is the objective of the validation.

```
{
"poi": [{
    "PoiId": "1234",
    "offeringName": "Test1",
    "totalOfferingAmount": -15,
    "offeringTypeQualifier": "Test",
    "productTypeQualifier": "Product",
    "quantity": -1,
    "messages": [],
    "autoAdd": false,
    "autoAction": "removed",
    "addedByProcessor": true,
    "qualificationLevel": "FQ",
    "qualificationDetails": []
}, {
    "PoiId": "5678",
    "offeringName": "Test2",
    "totalOfferingAmount": -15,
    "offeringTypeQualifier": "Test",
    "productTypeQualifier": "Product",
    "quantity": -1,
    "messages": [],
    "autoAdd": false,
    "autoAction": "removed",
    "addedByProcessor": true,
    "qualificationLevel": "FQ",
    "qualificationDetails": []
}],
"isPOIOfferValidForCheckout": true,
"_status": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **poi** is an array of objects, you should be validating like this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var poi = response.poi;
tests['First PoiId is 1234'] = poi[0].PoiId === 1234;
tests['Second PoiId is 5678'] = poi[1].PoiId === 5678;
```